# difference between put the fire out and put out the fire

Tags: phrasal-verbs

what is the difference between these two?

`put out the fire` and `put the fire out`

what are the use cases?
do they mean the same or not?
another example is take off

take it off or take off it => here it seems the first one is correct

Comment: Note that "put out" is something of an idiom here, and it means "extinguish" in several contexts.

Comment: With "Put out the fire"/"Put the fire out" I can't think of a context in which one would work and the other wouldn't. They mean the same. "Take off it" is not grammatical, though we do say "I take my shirt off" and "I take off my shirt" interchangeably.

Comment: I agree with @OldBrixtonian, although if the fire were in some sort of portable brazier and you wanted the whole thing moved outside I thing only put the fire out could result in the fire still burning.

Comment: thank you, everybody. when you want to say a firefighter to extinguish the fire, how is it used?